# how to obtain first digit of zip codes beginning with zero in PHP

Tags: php, substring

The following PHP code should return a `$zone` of 5. And `$postcodeprefix` should be 075.

I believe this is not working because PHP is treating the postal code as an integer instead of a string. I have tried things like:

```
$postcode = $postcode." ";
$postcode = strval($postcode);
```

None of the things I have tried have worked.

What is the fix?

```
$postcode = 07558;//comes from database as a number. I can't change this.
$postcode = $postcode." "; //one of various ways I have tried to turn this into a string
$postcode = trim($postcode);

$zone = 99;
$postcodeprefix = substr($postcode,0,3);
echo "\$postcodeprefix=".$postcodeprefix."\n";
$postcodeprefixkey = substr($postcode,0,1); //this is the first postcode digit
echo "\$postcodeprefixkey=".$postcodeprefixkey."\n";
if ($postcodeprefixkey == 0) {
                //any range containing postcode which starts with 0
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 001 && $postcodeprefix <= 005) {$zone = 5;} else
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 006 && $postcodeprefix <= 009) {$zone = 6;} else
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 010 && $postcodeprefix <= 029) {$zone = 5;} else
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 030 && $postcodeprefix <= 054) {$zone = 6;} else
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 055 && $postcodeprefix <= 055) {$zone = 5;} else
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 056 && $postcodeprefix <= 059) {$zone = 6;} else
                if ($postcodeprefix >= 060 && $postcodeprefix <= 098) {$zone = 5;}
            } 
echo "\$zone=".$zone;
```

Comment: $postcode = (string)$postcode;

Comment: @slime - that does not work. I tried it.

Comment: ZIP codes are strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
$postcode = 07558;//comes from database as a number. I can't change this.
```

In here, $postcode is already an octal value and

```
$postcode = 07558;//comes from database as a number. I can't change this.
$postcode = $postcode." "; //one of various ways I have tried to turn this into a string
$postcode = trim($postcode);

echo $postcode;
```

gives 493.

Treat it as a number, it's quite easier:

```
$postcode  =  7558; // 07558 would be treated as octal value!

$postcodeC = intval($postcode / 100); // 075

if ( $postcodeC < 100 )
{
       ...
       if ($postcodeC >= 60 && $postcodeC <= 98) {$zone = 5;}
       ...
}
```

Comment: That does not work. You can check it here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/. Instead of 075 as you expected in your comment, you actually get 4. 07558 is being treated as an octal number in PHP. I would prefer to use strings.

Comment: Yes, that's because PHP is interpreting `$postcode  =  07558;` as octal value and not as a base 10. I've changed that above.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I cannot change the data in the database. So I cannot remove leading zeros from zip codes, nor would I want to do that. It would have size effects in other parts of the code.

Comment: Then you might add a prefix already in the select from the database? Like `SELECT .... CONCAT("XX", zip) ...` which the gives `XX07558`

Comment: Yes, a prefix is what I ended up doing... that does work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally solved it. I tricked the substr() function into not re-interpreting the $postcode as an octal number with this technique:

```
        $postcodeprefix = substr("x".$postcode,1,3);
        $postcodeprefixkey = substr("x".$postcode,1,1);
```